A problem inspired by the 2022 IMO P5
The 2022 IMO P5 goes as the following:
$$a^p=b!+p$$
If we do a little remake we get:
$$a!=b^p+p$$
I tried to find if the problem($a!=b^p+p$) has already been solved, but i came up empty handed. I aslo tried to solve the problem, but that didn't work very well. Can someone try to solve it? My attempt of solving it is as following.
We dived the problem into 2 cases:

$a<p$.
It's trivial that $b<a$ (If not then $b^p>a!$). Beacuse of $b<a$ we get $b\mid a!$ so $b\mid p$, but then $b=1,p$.
(1)  $b=1$. Then $a!-p=1$
Does this equation have infinitly many solutions?
(2)  $b=p$. But this is a contradiction beacuse $b<a<p$

$a\ge p$.
We get that $v_p(RHS)=1$ so $a<2p$. We also know that $p\mid a!$ beacuse $a\ge p$ so $p\mid b$. Here I have a question: Can we prove that $a\ge b$ beacuse of $a<2p$? If that claim holds then $b<2p$ and $p\mid b$ so $b=p$. Here I also got stuck. Can somebody help?
I apologize for all my grammer mistakes. $a,b$ are natural numbers, but p is a prime number.



This is not clear.  What's the question?  On its face, solving for $(a,b,p)$ with $a^p=b!+p$ isn't the same as solving for $a!=b^p+p$ but of course you haven't said what sort of values $(a,b,p)$ might take.

I apologize for that, I'm solving  $a!=b^p+p$, $a,b$ are natural numbers, $p$ is a prime

And is $p$ meant to be a prime?  Are you saying that this is equivalent to the other problem or is this intended to be a new problem?  If you take $b=1$  in that expression you get $a!-1=p$, not what you said.

It isn't known whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $n!\pm 1$, so your version is unlikely to have a sensible answer (which of course doesn't mean that nothing can be said about it).

Yes, p is a prime number. I posted the IMO problem just so everyone can see where I got the inspiration. Sorry for the confusion, but I'm trying to solve $a!=b^p+p$

I suggest editing your post for clarity.  State the problem you are interested in clearly, with all assumptions spelled out.  referencing the old problem as inspiration is good, of course, though mentioning that $n!-1=p$ is already unsolved is helpful as it manages expectations.  If you have non-trivial solutions of other types it would be worth providing those.

Are you interested in a list of solutions for some ranges for $a$ and $p$ ? I think , they soon thin out with the magnitude of $a^p$. As others have pointed out , it will be hopeless to find all solutions.

A search for small solutions yields $3! = 2^2 + 2 = 1^5 + 5$ and $4! = 1^{23} + 23$.

$a! - 1$ is prime for $a$ in OEIS sequence A002982

The case $p=2$ can easily be solved. If we exclude the primorial primes (which are listed upto an extreme magnitude) , we have that the base is greater than $1$ allowing us to enumerate all possible cases below some limit magnitude for the factorial and the power.

The first case is an unsolved problem - it's unknown whether there are infinitely primes in form $a!-1$.
The second case can be solved. As you said we know that $a<2p$ and $p|b$. Let $b=kp$ for natural number $k$. We have to solve $a!=(kp)^p+p$.
Firstly let's prove that $k<a$. Assuming $k\geq a$ we have
$$ (kp)^p+p>k^pp^p>k^p\cdot p!> \underbrace{a(a-1)\ldots (p+1)}_{less \ than \ p \ factors}\cdot p! =a! $$
and we get a contradiction.
Because $k<a$ then $k|a!$ so $k|(kp)^p+p$ which means $k|p$ so $k=1$ or $k=p$.
Let's consider case when $k=1$. Our equation is now $a!=p^p+p=p(p^{p-1}+1)$. If $p=2$ we get $a!=6$ so one of solutions is triplet $(3, 2, 2)$. If $p=3$ we get $a!=30$ which is impossible. If $p>3$ then 3 divides $a!$ but 3 does not divide neither $p$ nor $p^{p-1}+1$ (because $p-1$ is even so $p^{p-1}\equiv 1$ (mod 3)).
Now let's consider case when $k=p$. We have $p^{2p}+p=a!$ but $p=2$ is not a solution and for any integer $n\geq3$ holds inequality $n^{2n}>(2n)!$ which can be proved using simple induction. That means there are no solutions when $k=p$.
